# Image path from static folder using Google App Engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, static

I am working on a website. I am using Python 2.7 and Google App Engine. I want to add some images on my website like logo, background image etc. I have saved these images in static folder. Now i want to use these saved images in my web, But i can't find the right path for this to use this image. I tried many paths, but no one worked. Anyone can tell me?

Comment: Can You explain a bit more?

Comment: Please add more info, like what's in your app.yaml, your current project structure...

Comment: have you mapped your static folder correctly ? -https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/serving-static-files

Comment: Thank you jeffrey and varun, the problem was that i didn't called rightly the static folder, now it just takes /static/file_name.